# Is it possible to set a decorator value once and validate using it?

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

I was looking into if it's possible to set the n value once and reuse it whenever this decorator is called.
Is there any alternative approach than passing the n value whenever the decorator is called?
Or is the best way to just go with a regular decorator and have the n as a global value?

```
def validate_length(n):
    def decorator(func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            if len(args[1]) < n:
                raise ValueError(f"Dataframe must have at least {n} rows.")
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

Comment: You could make `n` an optional parameter by setting it a default value, e.g., `def validate_length(n=42):`.

Comment: @JacobLee I would want to be able to control this dynamically, so setting it to a default isn't the way to go

Comment: Decorator arguments are evaluated when you're defining the decorated function, not when the function is called.

Comment: Can you show how you want to use this decorator?

Comment: @Barmar I want to ensure that my dataframe has sufficient length, so I would call this decorator on the function handling it. The sufficient length param (n) can come from user input.

Comment: The wrapper can add additional arguments to the function it's wrapping, so you can pass `n` there.

Comment: @Barmar But the issue with that approach is, if I have x number of functions handling dataframe operations, each of those would now have to have an additional field for the `n` value which would be passed to the decorator. Are you aware of any other approach that doesn't involve passing it in as an argument from the function on which it is being called? PS: this `n` value would remain same throughout execution. Would only be changed once.

Comment: if it's just set once for everything, a global variable probably is the way to go.